# Unable to run Vue.js 3 along with django code

Tags: html, django, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm unable to load Vue.js 3 in my django code. I used Vue from the CDN.

Vue import:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Html:

```
<table id="todaysappts" class="table table-bordered {{ ctype }}">
    <thead class="tblheadercol2">
        <tr>
            {% if "expired" in ctype %}
            Appointments on {{ liveslist_date }}

            {% else %}
            <strong>Today's Appointments</strong>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-24">
            Here: [[ message ]]
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-24">
            Total:{{ appt_total }} Seen:{{ appt_seen }} Remaining:{{ appt_not_seen }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th><i class="green far fa-mobile-android-alt fa-lg "></i></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ... Snipped ...
```

JS:

```js
console.log(`Vue code inserted`);
const app = Vue.createApp({
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello Vue!",
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {},
});
app.mount("#todaysappts");
```

JS console output:

```
You are running a development build of Vue.
Make sure to use the production build (*.prod.js) when deploying for production.
Vue code inserted
```

Html output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-24">
    Here: [[ message ]]
    </div>
</div>
```

So, my variable message is not getting interpolated, and the variable name is being printed, with the brackets. How I do it solve this? Apparently vue is loaded, and there are no errors.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: replace `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>`  by bundled script  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>` would fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is trying to mount to a div with id `todaysappts` which doesn't exist.  Add the id to the root element:

```js
console.log(`Vue code inserted`);
const app = Vue.createApp({
delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
data() {
    return {
    message: "Hello Vue!",
    };
},
computed: {},
methods: {},
});
app.mount("#todaysappts");
```

```html
<div id="todaysappts" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-24">
    Here: [[ message ]]
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

***After the post edit:*** Also, the HTML is invalid because there are `<div>` elements inserted directly into the table template.

Comment: Sorry for omitting to add the root element. I have edited with more code

Comment: It's because your HTML is invalid.  You can't have a `<div>` as a direct descendant of a `<table>`, it should be inside a `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Comment: You put me on the right path. The id element was in the wrong ancestor.